# Смещение position: absolute элемента при изменении размеров браузера

Tags: css

Как сделать так, чтобы элемент, которому задано `position: absolute`, при уменьшении окна браузера по ширине смещался к центру, как все остальные элементы?

```css
.logo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background-color: #244c5f;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 101px;
    left: 900px;
    text-align: center;
    font: 24px/8 Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: azure;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>1</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="logo">hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос.

Comment: указать top и left в %

Answer (score 2):

Например:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5rem 2rem;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  text-align: center;
}


.wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.abs {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Обычный блок</div>

  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="box abs">Блок с position: absolute;</div>
  </div>
```